# Архитектура ОС Линукс

Tags: c++, c, unix

Передо мной схема  ОС. Иду сверху вниз - Applications, System Libraries, System Call Interface etc. Причем на картинке показано, что есть возможность не юзать System Libraries а сразу очутиться на уровне System Call Interface.

Как я могу это осуществить?

Я не знаю таких случаев. Как я понимаю мой код работает по такой примерной схеме - например вызываю функцию fcntl(...), так я использую System Libraries, потом эта системная функция генерит прерывание и так мы переходим на уровень System Call Interface. Итого чтобы мне проскочить уровень Системной библиотеки, мне нужно сразу генерить прерывание с кодом который закреплен за обработчиком прерывания функции fcntl(...)...а как тогда этому обработчику аргументы передать...

Comment: Через регистры http://sys.readthedocs.io/en/latest/doc/07_calling_system_calls.html   http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/

Comment: Т.е. если я на ассемблере буду писать? Сначала кладу в регистры аргументы и делаю call

Comment: да. только не call, а syscall, он же `int 0x80` на архитектуре intel. И в первой ссылке, что я дал есть примеры на ассемблере

Comment: Не могли бы ещё подсказать, не могу найти информацию о том что значит параметр usecs/call в утилите strace, когда смотришь статистику по сисколам

Comment: не знаю. но судя по названию это время выполнения вызова в микросекундах